# Change sequence of elements on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap row with two cols that break at large screen device. On desktop `one` comes before `two` - is there an easy tweak to adjust the sequence of both elements, so that on mobile `two` comes before `one`.

Do I need JS to do so?

```
<div className="row mx-0">
    <div className="col-lg-6 one">
         //
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-6 two">
         //
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#reordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#reordering) responsive classes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col order-lg-2 order-1">Column 1</div>
  <div class="col order-lg-1 order-2">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mx-0">
<div class="bg-light col order-lg-2 order-1">Column 1
</div>
<div class="bg-secondary text-white col order-lg-1 order-2">Column 2
</div>
</div>
</div>
```